# How to call Code Behind from server side

Tags: c#

I have a checkbox with event like this:

```
protected void cbRating1WithoutExceptionP1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbRating1WithoutExceptionP1.Checked == true)
            {
                cbRating1WithExceptionP1.Checked = false;
                cbRating1WithExceptionP1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                cbRating1WithExceptionP1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

How to call that event from server side?

```
foreach (string oWithException in oWithExceptions)
                        {
                            switch (oWithException.Trim())
                            {
                                case "P1":
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP1.Checked = true;
cbRating1WithoutExceptionP1_CheckedChanged(new object, new EventArgs);
                                    break;
                                case "P2":
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP2.Checked = true;
                                    break;
                                case "P3":
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP3.Checked = true;
                                    break;
                                case "P4":
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP4.Checked = true;
                                    break;
                                case "P5":
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP5.Checked = true;
                                    break;
                                case "NOT_ALLOWED":
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionNotAllowed.Checked = true;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP1.Checked = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP1.Enabled = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP2.Checked = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP2.Enabled = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP3.Checked = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP3.Enabled = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP4.Checked = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP4.Enabled = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP5.Checked = false;
                                    cbRating2WithExceptionP5.Enabled = false;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Like this:

```
cbRating1WithoutExceptionP1_CheckedChanged(new object, new EventArgs);
```

Is that possible to call the event from server side without create a function?

Comment: What do you mean by calling event from server side.This event is already at server side.

Comment: use like this `cbRating1WithoutExceptionP1_CheckedChanged(null, new EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: Or pull the relevant code into another method and call that method both from the event handler and your other places

Comment: Excellent! @Ganesh_Devlekar   thank you very much, Sir...
AllanS.Hansen: I do not want to create new function. That is why  I put "without create a function" at the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Like This if You wants to Only Call Your method:

```
cbRating1WithoutExceptionP1_CheckedChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: at my code, like this: 
                                    cbRating1WithoutExceptionP1_CheckedChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);

Comment: @irhabymailed4u yes right it should be.i did mistake now corrected